# Remove select menu option from other select menus on page based on value

Tags: jquery

I have a form that contains 10 select menus , each one containing 20 options .

I want to make the user not be able to select the same value from the select menus , 
If he chooses one option it will be removed from other menus but not from the current menu, and when he changes his choice the option will show again and the new choice will hide ..

I can't figure out a way to do that , so I will appreciate your help . thank you

Comment: Can you please show the code of what you have been trying so far? Will make it alot easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you , i have written this in JQuery so necessary script files must be included for it to work

```
(function () {
    var previous;

    $("select").on('focus', function () {
        previous = this.value;
    }).change(function(){
    $elm=$(this).children('option:selected');
    $a=$elm.val();
    $('[value='+$a+']').not( $elm).hide();
     $('[value='+previous+']').not( $elm).show();   

    });
})();
```

below is a demo

> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d373A/5/)

Comment: This code does not work on MacOS Chrome and on Windows Safari, any idea of what makes the problem please ?

Comment: may be your script runs before select is loaded
put the code in $(document).ready() function ,i think that will work. thank you

Comment: The problem was caused by the .hide() function , I solved by replacing it by .attr('disabled', 'disabled');